# iOS: 3 Strings into one hash. Find other string from hash of 2 strings

Tags: swift, hash

I have three strings : StrA, StrB, StrC.
And their hash is `YT56ejff653499TYK`

Now, if someone give me hash of StrA, StrB and its hash is IEoeuor749Hueiur7x, is there a way to extract StrC from `YT56ejff653499TYK` and `IEoeuor749Hueiur7x`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function: *map data of arbitrary size to fixed-size values*. There is no such thing as "extracting" a string from a hash.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are referring to some of the standard one-way hash functions like SHA-2 or similar, this should never be possible.

For example, if this was possible by any mean  it would make the password hash salting technique essentially a disclosure of the original password.

In short, with a one-way hash function which is not broken this should not be possible.

Comment: There could be specific hashes that have a property like this, but they wouldn't be used for cryptography. An example would be a [rolling hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_hash), which could be used to quickly find substring in strings.